# Product of standard parabolic subgroups

Tags: reductive-groups

Consider a quasi-split reductive group $G$ over a field $k$. Let $B$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$, and let $P, Q$ be two parabolic subgroups of $G$ that contain $B$. Is the product set $PQ = \{xy| x \in P(k), y \in Q(k)\}$ a group?

Comment: I think that the unique possibilty is $P\subset Q$ or $Q\subset P$ and this should be a general property of groups with a $BN$ pair (or Tits system). Attached to your context is a Weyl group $W$ and and a distinguished generating subset $S\subset W$ of involutions. Any parabolic subgroup $M$ containing $B$ writes $M=B<T_M >B$ for a well determined subset $T_M$ of $S$. The game is to use the fact that $PQ$ is a group to prove that $S_P \subset  S_Q$, or $S_Q\subset S_P$. For this use the properties of Tits systems for the product of cosets $(Bw_1 B).(Bw_2 B)$.

Comment: @PaulBroussous: I suppose you mean that, *if* $PQ$ is a group, then either $P \subset Q$ or $Q \subset P$? (I misunderstood your first sentence on a first reading.)

Comment: @Paul Broussous: The OP does not specify that $G$ is simple, so I think there are other examples.  For instance, for the split semisimple group $G=\textbf{SL}_2\times \textbf{SL}_2$ with Borel subgroup $B\times B$, then $P=\textbf{SL}_2\times B$ and $Q=B\times \textbf{SL}_2$ gives one example.

Comment: You're perfectly right. One needs to assume that the root system of $G$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications! I have a follow up question: In the above setting, could it instead be that the product $N_P N_Q$ of the unipotent parts of $P, Q$ is a group?